# Relation OneToOne cascade="persist, remove" not work

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a relationship OneToOne bidirectional, configurate how cascade persis, remove, but when i call controller eliminarPersonaFisicaAction, this show the next error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM entidad WHERE id = ?' with params [84]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`xxx`.`personafisica`, CONSTRAINT `FK_D55D20169B1A19BB` FOREIGN KEY (`id_entidad`) REFERENCES `entidad` (`id`))
```

This is my configure in entities:
First entity:

```
//code
/**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="XXX\EntidadBundle\Entity\PersonaFisica", mappedBy="entidad", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="persona_fisica_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $personaFisica;
//code
```

Second entity:

```
//code
/**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="XXX\EntidadBundle\Entity\Entidad", inversedBy="personaFisica", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_entidad", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $entidad;
//code
```

eliminarPersonaFisicaAction:

```
public function eliminarPersonaFisicaAction($id){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $personaFisica = $em->getRepository("EntidadBundle:Entidad")->find($id);
    if($personaFisica->getPresupuestosEnLosQueEsContacto()->isEmpty() && $personaFisica->getPresupuestos()->isEmpty() && $personaFisica->getDocumentos()->isEmpty() && $personaFisica->getAsignacionesExternas()->isEmpty()){
        $em->remove($personaFisica);
    }
    $em->flush();
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('ver_personas_fisicas'));
}
```

Comment: Can you also put the 'show create table' output here? Looks like you have problem with the DB, not with doctrine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please note that `cascade={"persist", "remove"}` only affect the internal Doctrine2 persistence and removal. It has nothing to do with the database.

In order to tell DB to explicitly add 'onDelete' property to the column you should use `onDelete="CASCADE"`in `JoinColumn` config.

```
//code
/**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="XXX\EntidadBundle\Entity\PersonaFisica", mappedBy="entidad", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="persona_fisica_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     **/
    private $personaFisica;
//code
```

You don't need to specify `JoinColumn` on two tables, it is enough that only one table have extra id field. From what I see in your code you should add `JoinColumn` to Entidad entity. That will make Entidad entity to be deleted when PersonaFisica is deleted.

Comment: Yes, joinColumn incorrectly... but now i get the next error: Notice: Undefined index: persona_fisica_id, Why @Stepashka?

Comment: Sorry, I've confused you with the joinColumn. My example was also wrong. I've removed it from the answer. Usually the joinColumn is defined only on one side. That confused me. I think the current answer should solve your problem.

Comment: No problem! But i have configured joinColum onDelete="CASCADE" and continue this error

Comment: Have you updated the DB schema? I've updated the answer again. Mentioned the `JoinColumn` proper placement idea.

Comment: Can you post the DB schema for that tables to your question and the latest error? There should be foreign key onDelete cascade property there.

Comment: Wow! I 've put onDelete="Cascade" in the two entities and work ! Thanks!

Comment: saying just @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE") is also worked, you don't have to define other parameters of JoinColumn